# yii2 kartik input widget not working properly

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I added buttons for delete and drag but not working, my code in the view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [

   'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 
     'id'=>'inputFile'],
   'pluginOptions' => [
   'rtl'=>'true',
   'fileActionSettings'=>['showZoom'=>true, 'showRemove' =>true, 
   'showDrag'=>true],
   'previewFileType' => 'image',
   'maxFileCount' => 4,
   'showUpload' => false,
   ]
]);
```

Where are i making mistakes?

Comment: See uses here: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

Comment: Thanks but I did not find anything there, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

When using **FORM submission** mode (without uploadUrl).  in this scenario you cannot REMOVE preview thumbnails before they are uploaded - ONE by ONE (you can only **clear all** - this is a native HTML FILE input limitation as one cannot edit the files in the input). in this case we must add uploadUrl:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [

      'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 
       'id'=>'inputFile'],
       'pluginOptions' => [
       'uploadUrl' => '/site/index',
       'rtl'=>'true',
       'fileActionSettings'=>['showZoom'=>true, 'showRemove' =>true, 
       'showDrag'=>true],
       'previewFileType' => 'image',
       'maxFileCount' => 4,
       'showUpload' => false,
       ]
    ]);
```

**This is ajax submission mode** with uploadUrl.